# Enlazar <select> con datos AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

solicito de su colaboracion para que me indiquen la manera de poder enlazar los datos de un objeto con un `<select>`

```
app.controller('nombreCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.nino = {
    nombre: 'Julian',
    sexo: 1,
    edad: 0,
    procedencia: "0",
    etnia: "2",
    municipio: "1",
    fase: "1",
    estado: "1",
    id_alimento: '2'
  };

  $scope.alimentos = [{
    id_alimento: '1',
    nombre: 'Almuerzo'
  }, {
    id_alimento: '2',
    nombre: 'Desayuno'
  }, {
    id_alimento: '3',
    nombre: 'Cena'
  }]
}])


  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 texto-izq" >Comida</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="select" ng-model="nino.id_alimento">
        <option ng-repeat="dato in alimentos" value="dato.id_alimento">
          {{dato.nombre}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

lo que necesito es enlazar los datos del niño id_alimento con el arreglo de alimentos

Comment: Siempre debes usar [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) en lugar de `ng-repeat` para crear las opciones de tu select. La razón es que `ng-repeat` te creará un nuevo `$scope` por cada elemento mientras que `ng-options` no lo hará ya que está diseñado específicamente para tratar con las opciones de un select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes combinar `<options>` con `ng-selected`, ten en cuenta que también debes *interpolar* el `value`.

Saludos.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('nombreCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.nino = {
      nombre: 'Julian',
      sexo: 1,
      edad: 0,
      procedencia: "0",
      etnia: "2",
      municipio: "1",
      fase: "1",
      estado: "1",
      id_alimento: '2'
    };

    $scope.alimentos = [{
      id_alimento: '1',
      nombre: 'Almuerzo'
    }, {
      id_alimento: '2',
      nombre: 'Desayuno'
    }, {
      id_alimento: '3',
      nombre: 'Cena'
    }]
  }
])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="nombreCtrl">
  <select id="select" ng-model="nino.id_alimento">
    <option ng-repeat="dato in alimentos" 
            value="{{dato.id_alimento}}" 
            ng-selected="{{dato.id_alimento == nino.id_alimento}}">
      {{dato.nombre}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: esta genial mil gracias, es posible que me puedas explicar para qu se usa `track by $index`

Comment: lo agregue por constumbre. Si usas `track by` ya se por el $index o un id, ng-repeat no recrea el dom cada vez que dibuja sino que mantiene los elementos creados la primera vez acualizandolos. Se recomienda usarlo siempre por motivos de performance. voy a sacarlo de la respuesta para que no sea confuso. gracias